# at91sam7 :interrupt for receiving a new a character uart

Tags: c, embedded

I tried receiving a character using `uart` protocol but after receiving the very first character the `Receiver Holding Register` (RHR) stores it and after it's read then its value doesn't change. But how can I know that a new character is received let it be the same character received before.

I am using this loop:

```
while((AT91C_BASE_US0->US_CSR & AT91C_US_RXRDY) == AT91C_US_RXRDY) 
buffer=AT91C_BASE_US0->US_RHR;
```

and also whenever the condition is `true` and the receiver doesn't receive a new character then the buffer stores the previous character received and remains the same utill a new character is received and this process goes on and on and on...!

Comment: Have a look at http://siwawi.bauing.uni-kl.de/avr_projects/arm_projects/index_at91.html#at91uart

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov tell me which interrupt shall i use to know the new character is received in the RHR

Comment: Actually i got the answer. the loop should be like

'while(!(AT91C_BASE_US0->US_CSR & AT91C_US_RXRDY)
{
}
buffer=AT91C_BASE_US0->US_RHR;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, I just had to the following:

```
while(!(AT91C_BASE_US0->US_CSR & AT91C_US_RXRDY){}
 buffer=AT91C_BASE_US0->US_RHR;
```

Explanation: There is no such interrupt that can be used, I had to continuously keep checking when both of them (CSR and RXRDY) is turning true, which gives an indication of new character received. (Basically handwritten interrupt)